# Form submiting with Play/Scala and MongoDB

Tags: forms, mongodb, scala, playframework, salat

I am currently writing my first application with scala (2.11), Playframework (2.2.3) and MongoDB (with Salat). Since I dont really know any of them too well I've got a bit of a beginner problem: I can't submit data from a form.

I am not really sure if anyone can help me with my precise problem, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

my current error is:

```
[error] .../app/controllers/api/Users.scala:96: Cannot find Formatter type class for se.radley.plugin.salat.Binders.ObjectId. Perhaps you will need to import play.api.data.format.Formats._ 
[error]     "id" -> of[ObjectId],
[error]               ^
[error] .../app/views/user.scala.html:7: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.EssentialAction
[error]  required: String
[error]     @helper.form(action = new play.api.mvc.Call("POST",api.Users.create)) {
```

Here's my code: *view - users.scala.html*:

```
@(userForm: Form[User])
@import views.html.helper._
@main("create new user") {
     @helper.form(action = new play.api.mvc.Call("POST",api.Users.create)) {
        @helper.inputText(userForm("username"))
        <!-- other fields -->
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
    }
}
```

parts of my *controller - Users.scala*:

```
 def create = JsonAction[SUser] { user =>
    SUser.save(user, WriteConcern.Safe)
    Ok(views.html.user(userForm)),

 def createForm() = Action {
   Ok(views.html.user(userForm))
 }

val userForm = Form(mapping(
  "id" -> of[ObjectId],
  "username" -> nonEmptyText,
  // other fields
)(SUser.apply)(SUser.unapply))
```

my *route* for this request:

```
POST    /user               controllers.api.Users.create()
```

and finally my *model - User.scala*:

```
case class User(
    id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
    username: String,
    // etc

object User extends UserDAO with UserJson

trait UserDAO extends ModelCompanion[User, ObjectId] {
  def collection = mongoCollection("users")
  val dao = new SalatDAO[User, ObjectId](collection) {} /* other methods */ }

trait UserJson {

implicit val userJsonWrite = new Writes[User] {
  def writes(u: User): JsValue = {
    Json.obj(
      "id" -> u.id,
      "username" -> u.username,
      /* etc */ )}} 

implicit val userJsonRead = (
  (__ \ 'id).read[ObjectId] ~
  (__ \ 'username).read[String] ~
  /* etc */ ) (User.apply _)
```

I tried lots of different variations based on https://github.com/leon/play-salat with the help of Play for Scala (Manning) and google links I found on that topic. It seems to me this is a pretty obvious problem, but as I said I am very new to these topics. If anyone can point me at a right direction or even send me a tutorial or something it would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I just edited the code above since I changed some parts of it. Now my problem is the missing formatter and the conversion from EssentialAction to String. Unfortunately I dont really find tutorials on the internet on that topic

Comment: well I dont think anyone can help me with my current question. I simply have to learn more about all new frameworks etc. I'll come back when I actually know what I'm doing